# When we do really need the axiom of choice

Tags: equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice

Let us suppose that $\{X_i: i \in I\}$ is a family of nonempty subsets of $X$ such that either $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ or $X_i=X_j$ for all $i,j \in I$.

*Fact using the AC:* We can define an equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $I$ by saying that $i\equiv j$ if and only if $X_i=X_j$. Denote by $K$ the quotient space of $I$ modulo $\equiv$. Then, for each $k \in K$, we can find equivalence class of $X^\bullet_k$. By the AC, we can choose $X_k$ in the class $X_k^\bullet$, for each $k \in K$. It follows that $\{X_k:k \in K\}$ is made by pairwise disjoint sets and $\cup_k X_k=\cup_i X_i$.

**Question:** Do we really need the axiom of choice to obtain the existence of the family $\{X_k:k \in K\}$?

Comment: Do you mean to define $i\equiv j$ rather than $X_i\equiv X_j$, so you have an equivalence class on $I$?  Otherwise your equivalence relation is trivial...

Comment: Please address Eric's comment and also tell us what you mean by $K$?

Comment: I edited the question, you're right

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: thanks for the clarification. You don't need AC - see my answer.

Comment: I saw, thanks Rob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $K$ is the quotient set of $I$ modulo the equivalence relation $\equiv$ defined by $i \equiv j$ iff $X_i = X_j$ and you are trying to construct a family of sets indexed by $K$ that eliminates possible duplication in the $X_i$. Then for $k$ in $K$ you can define $X^{\bullet}_k = \bigcup_{i\in k} X_i$ to define the family of sets you want without using AC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do in fact need choice.

It is consistent with ZF (= set theory without choice) that there is a set $I$ which can be partitioned into pairs of sets $I=\bigcup_{g\in G}J_g$, $\vert J_g\vert =2$, but such that there is no choice function for $\{J_g: g\in G\}$.

We can now construct a set $X_i$ $(i\in I)$ of sets such that $X_i=X_{i'}$ iff $i, i'\in J_g$ for some $g$, and $X_i\cap X_{i'}=\emptyset$ otherwise.

---

More generally: suppose that the axiom of choice fails, and $\{Y_g: g\in G\}$ is a family of disjoint sets with no choice function. Let $I=\bigcup_{g\in G} Y_g$, and let (for $i\in I$) $X_i=\{Y_g\}$ where $i\in Y_g$. Note that $X_i=X_{i'}$ iff $i$ and $i'$ are in the same $Y_g$. Then the set $\{X_i: i\in I\}$ has no "selector" set. So, in fact, your statement is *equivalent to* the axiom of choice.

Comment: But you don't need to choose representatives to form the set of equivalence classes $K$ apparently asked for in the question. The OP needs to answer my comment on the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah, I misread the question. I'm leaving this answer up since it was unclear what was meant.

Comment: perhaps you could explain in your answer the reading of the question you had in mind.

Comment: @RobArthan The sentence "By the AC, we can choose $X_k$ in the class $X_k^\cdot$, for each $k\in K$" (and the following) suggested that what was really wanted was a selection function picking some index $i_k$ with $X_{i_k}\in X_k^\cdot$ for each $k\in K$.

Comment: That was a proof using the AC, indeed.. and I was just asking whether it was really necessary, isn't it? :)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti It depends exactly what you were asking. I interpreted your question as asking for a set of *indices* - that is, a set $K\subseteq I$ such that for each $i\in I$ there is exactly one $k\in K$ with $X_k=X_i$. For that, choice **is needed**.

Comment: Now i see your point :)